# Random Distribution Calculation

Tags: python, java

If i specify a number, is there a way to assign a random portion of that number as a total to several groups?

e.g Total 1.

Group 1 - 0.1
Group 2 - 0.3
Group 3 - 0.4
Group 4 - 0.2

Comment: Please, 1. decide on a language - this is probably possible in every language, but answers will be different. 2. clarify what you mean by "group" and "random portion" (I've got a rough idea based on your example, but I'm not completetly sure, e.g. how precisely do the "portions" need to sum to the input number?)

Comment: It will be best to just pick a language, try to implement this, and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do in java ...

You generate a random number from 1 to 100 by using a function like this

```
// min = 1 max=100 in your case
public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}
```

Then in your function which selects the element you do like this ...

> Group 1 - 0.1 Group 2 - 0.3 Group 3 - 0.4 Group 4 - 0.2

1. If the number is 1 to 10 select group 1.
2. If the number is 11 to 40 select group 2.
3. If the number is 41 to 80 select group 3
4. If the number is 81 to 100 select group 4

Its as easy as calculating percentages.

Does this solve your problem ? Let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't care about somewhat same distribution, you can just

```
void foo(){
  double total = 1.0;
  double[] group = new double[4];
  
  for(int i = 0; i < group.length-1; i++){
  //get random 0.0-1.0
  double rand = getRandom(0.0, 1.0);
  double portion = random * total
  group[i] = portion;
  total -= portion;
  }
  
  group[group.length-1] = total;
}
```

If you do care, you can set getRandom to your liking, f.e.

```
//get random 0.0-1.0
  double rand = getRandom(1.0/group.length*0.7, 1.0/group.length * 1.3);
```

so it will be 70% to 130% of the average.

Answer (score 0):

This method can distribute a value to an array or "groups" of that value type randomly,
you can switch out `double` with `int` or `float` as you see fit.

```
public void assignGroups(double[] groups, double number){
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<groups.length-1; i++){
        double randomNum  = rand.nextDouble()*number; // randomly picks number between 0 and the current amount left
        groups[i] = randomNum;
        number-=randomNum; // subtracts the random number from the total
    }
    groups[groups.length-1] = number; // sets the last value of the groups to the number left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java:

```
private static double roundValue(double value, int precision) {
    return (double) Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, precision))/ 
                    Math.pow(10, precision);
}

public static double[] generateGroups(double total, int groupsNumber, int precision){
    double[] result = new double[groupsNumber];
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < groupsNumber - 1; i++) {
        result[i] = roundValue((total - sum) * Math.random(), precision);
        sum += result[i];
    }
    result[groupsNumber-1] = roundValue((total - sum), precision);
    return result;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
   double[] result = generateGroups(1.0, 4, 1);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Python`:

```
from random import random

num_groups = 5  # Number of groups
total = 5  # The given number

base = [0.] + sorted(random() for _ in range(num_groups - 1)) + [1.]
portions = [(right - left) * total for left, right in zip(base[:-1], base[1:])]
```

Result (`print(portions)`): A list of length `num_groups` (number of groups) which contains the distributed `total` (given number):

```
[2.5749833618941995, 0.010389749273946869, 0.3718137712569358, 0.3725336641218424, 1.6702794534530752]
```